# Why does this call to Share cause an error?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I run this code (JupyterLab, but probably not relevant?)

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
yahoo = Share('YHOO')
print ( yahoo.get_open())
```

I get this error on the reference to Share:

```
RLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo's finance API has been [discontinued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050518/is-yql-datatables-org-down-as-of-may-17-18-2017) since the 17th of May of 2017.

Your code fails because `yahoo_finance` library was using the public API from Yahoo's finance. Nowadays there are other alternatives such as using [yfinance](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/), whose functionalities are pretty similar to the old `yahoo_finance`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I did get yfinance to work.